# Extra log in button showing

Tags: identity-server

On my new fresh install of Sitecore Identity Server, I see the extra log in button:

[image]

My understanding is this appears if you have an external identity server set up. But I do not. This is a fresh install. How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore 9.x use Identity Server (IS) out of the box (we also can consider that it is external Identity Server because it is installed as a separate application). So Sitecore 9.x expects that IS installed. The extra button usually appears when you don’t have an Identity Server installed or it is unavailable. As far as I understood, you haven’t installed IS and it is why you see the extra button.

Comment: Hi Artsem. I do have Sitecore Identity installed. Weirdly the identity server still works even though Sitecore "doesn't know" about it. I had to update sc.variable IdentityServerAuthority